# Dell XPS 13 9370 Touchpad Multi-touch / gestures 19.04

Tags: touchpad, xps

OK so i've done some digging and found a lot of references to a synaptics driver etc etc - i don't think that is my issue since all the clicks are working just fine and the movement is very smooth -- i just want to enable three finger swipes to change desktop environments because i'm too lazy to use the keyboard shortcuts - i am sure its doable and i've read that 'it works out of the box' in 18.04 - but i'd rather not go from 19.04 to 18.04.

my machine is dual booted with windows and everything in ubuntu is working very slick

xinput shows two 'mice'

⎜   ↳ DELL07E6:00 06CB:76AF Touchpad            id=13

⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse

i installed the xorg-synaptics driver solution i found on a separate thread - no change - i poked around in tweaks tool and the settings and i'm just not seeing where to enable three finger swipes.

Comment: that's a year ago, and no responses ...
also stuck with this problem, recently upgraded to 20.04...
it looks like we will have to wait for official Dell 20.04 support...